# Como girar um elemento no C#

Tags: c#

Estou criando um software que execute o vídeo com ângulo de 90º graus. 
Estou utilizando o axWindowsMediaPlayer (plugin disponibilizado pelo winform).

[image: Screenshot da aplicação]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RotationVideo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fileOpened = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (fileOpened.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = fileOpened.FileName;
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = textBox1.Text;
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não acredito que isso seja possível com esse componente em uma aplicação WindowsForms

Comment: imagino que seja pra exibir em televisores na vertical. Nesse caso, você pode rodar a imagem do computador e não o componente.